# Why does appending to dictionaries created with fromkeys method differ from appending to manually created dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I create two identical dictionaries containing lists using two different methods:

```
dictA = dict.fromkeys(["key1", "key2"], [])
dictB = {
    "key1": [],
    "key2": [],
}
```

Yet, when I append a random value or list to a specific key of each dictionary:

```
dictA["key2"].append(1)
dictB["key2"].append(1)
```

...I end up with different results:

```
{'key1': [1], 'key2': [1]}
{'key1': [], 'key2': [1]}
```

Why is that?

Comment: In the first case each value is a reference to the same array.

Comment: There is an easy way to make dictionaries with unique lists as values: `{key:list() for key in ('key1', 'key2')}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the default value of `dict.fromkeys()`, when mutable, points to a single object. You can do the test like this:

```
d = {}.fromkeys(['a', 'b'], [])

print(id(d['a']))
print(id(d['b']))
```

```
Out[115]: 2315628170504
Out[116]: 2315628170504
```

The value of the keys `'a'` and `'b'` points to the same object.

Comment: Is this expected behavior? Is there really a used case for this?

Comment: it is expected. the reason is quite complicated, here's some [introductory reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: @MichelF. This is pretty consistent across python. Get used to it. Multiple variables/keys/etc can and will refer to the exact same object.

Comment: @MichelF. That is the expected behavior. The doc string says _...and values set to value._. It makes sense when you want, say, integer 0 or a default string.  You are using a mutable container, but the thing is, how to copy objects to make the values unique is ambiguous. A list, okay, ... but then should that deep copy all contained objects? And what about a generic class `Foo`. What then? Since there isn't a good general choice for copying, the good choice is not to implement it in a foundation object such as list.